# 1 hour query, is there another way to do this?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

I saw a couple questions similar to this but none could answer my question, really.

I have two tables, and I am trying to find those rows where a match is found.
`user` has about 350,000 entries and `match` has about 55,000 entries. There are `UNIQUE` indices on both `user.name` as well as on `match.string`.

My query is:

```
SELECT user.name
FROM user
INNER JOIN match
on ( 
      (match.type = 'exact' AND user.name = match.string)
   OR (match.type = 'begin' AND user.name LIKE CONCAT(match.string, '%'))
   OR (match.type = 'end' AND user.name LIKE CONCAT('%', match.string))
)
```

The query is running for an hour now, and no end in sight.
Is there a faster way to do that?

I don't need this for regular production, but I think a query that runs for so long is unacceptable.

Comment: And indexes on match.type and em_exclusion.matchtype? Also, I don't think [CONCAT](http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/performance/id/5211) is [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - try match.string || '%' or similar. Your second condition is bound to provoke an FTS (full table scan).

Comment: @Vérace you say "try match.string || '%' ". how exactly do I do that? I tried to run only that part of the query, but it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry - I thought that I read somewhere that MySQL was going to start using the standard || (double pipe) string concatenation operator. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24777235/470530) and @DForck42 seems to think CONCAT is sargable. His idea for reversing computed colums will only work for [MySQL 5.7](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) - it does work for MariaDB (GA) though.

Comment: If you put the table date and structures up for download somewhere, I'll take a look. You can md5 anything potentially sensitive. For the computed column, you could perhaps use triggers to REVERSE a "shadow" column?

Answer (score 2):

No way!  Every 'end' is not optimizable because of the leading wildcard.  That means that if there are, say, a mere 3K 'end' entries in match, then there will be over a billion (350K * 3K) tests to perform!

The query can be partially optimized by

```
INDEX(type, string) -- in `match`
INDEX(name) -- in `user`
SELECT ... FROM user JOIN match ON match.type='exact' AND user.name=match.string
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM user JOIN match ON match.type='begin' AND user.name LIKE CONCAT...
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM user JOIN match ON match.type='end' AND user.name LIKE CONCAT...;
```

- The `match` INDEX minimizes the effort in finding the relevant rows.
- The `user` INDEX is useful for the first two SELECTs.
- The UNION lets the optimizer operate on each SELECT independently.
- The ALL avoid a de-dupping phase that is (I assume) unnecessary.

Have you considered a FULLTEXT index?  If it works, it will be a million times as fast.  (Perhaps literally a million!)

Here's a *kludge* that can make the third SELECT sargable (gee, I learned a new word!) -- Reverse both the match.string and the user.name, then do the LIKE like 'begin'.  No, don't use the REVERSE function in *this* query, actually build the two tables (or maybe a separate pair of tables) with the reversed strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would try breaking this down into three subqueries and then join the results using full outer joins.

```
select distinct coalesce(a.name, b.name, c.name)

from
    (
        select user.name
        from [user]
            inner join match
                on user.name = match.string
        where match.type = 'exact'
    ) a
    full outer join
    (
        select [user].name
        from [user]
            inner join match
                on user.name like concat(match.string, '%')
        where match.type = 'begin'
    ) b
        on a.name = b.name
    full outer join
    (
        select [user].name
        from [user]
            inner join match
                on user.name like concat('%', match.string)
        where match.type = 'end'
    ) c
        on a.name = c.name
```

The first and third subqueries should work pretty quick.  The second one I'm dubious about whether you can index for that, but I'm unsure.

edit: did a little bit of digging and it seems that you can index this, kinda.  According to [KM's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395881/95710) post here you can created a computed column that is the reverse of user.name and then run the like statement, having reversed your search text of course.

Comment: This creates a syntax error: full outer join ( select user.name from user in' at line 11

Comment: @koljanep i didn't expect it to work right out of the box, was more trying to provide a general layout for you to use.  As far as i can tell, without the actual database to play with, this should work.